# Type mismatch: inferred type is NameFragment but Context was expected - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, type-mismatch

I want to make a record audio permission request function when someone presses a button. I've gone through many google searches from 27 errors to only 2 errors.

I've searched many questions, but none of them are a solution of my problem.
Here's the Code for *fragment_edward.kt*:

```
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

private fun requestRecordAudioPermission(){
    var permissionsToRequest = mutableListOf<String>()
    if(!hasRecordAudioPermission())
        permissionsToRequest.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)


    if(permissionsToRequest.isNotEmpty()){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray(),0)
    }
}
```

**First error:**

`Type mismatch: inferred type is SlideshowFragment but Context was expected`

second error:
`Type mismarch: inferred type is SlideshowFragment but Activity was expected`

I really hope, that someone can help me.
Thank you all so much for every answer or question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know what this code does, but I think you are getting the errors here

> ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

and here

> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray(),0)

right?

If you are calling this code inside your fragment (which you do, because of the error messages), you should change it the following:

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

and

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), permissionsToRequest.toTypedArray(),0)
```